# Why is it so hard to draw rotated / wrapped text in graphics2D?

Tags: java, graphics

I am following up with my question here 
[Drawing wrapped text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094625/drawing-multi-lines-vertically/)

I see rotating working when I don't use the Textlayout but then it does not fit so I need to wrap but the [LineBreakMeasurer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/font/LineBreakMeasurer.html) does not work.

Either I am missing here something completely since it should not be too hard as I guess

Answer (score 1):

You try work the wrong way around. Don't attempt to rotate the text, instead rotate the drawing surface. Have a look at Graphics2D.rotate(). You can draw anything transformed using normal Graphics2D calls by applying an appropiate transformation to the Graphics2D before.

See the [Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html) for Examples.